Why thru axle was damaged?
Why the below trhu axle was damaged ?
Is it a misuse from my side or it's impossible to know.
(Probably I didn't screw it till the end before it was broken or maybe I applied to much force, when closing it.)
P.S. It's prequel to this question Can I use rear (thru) axle with crack for a few rides, before getting a new one?, but not related to it.


I was asked for a full axle picture:


It will be difficult to tell from these 320×240 jpegs. Could you replace them with something more usable?

@g.kertesz, you mean with higher resolution ?

OK, nice, I see you got it fixed.

Do you have a picture of the whole axle (from one end to the other) as well?

@BenediktBauer. I've added a picture of the whole axle.

I was wrong so I decided to rewrite my answer.
I went to look at the bike in my shed that has a similar axle. This axle type works so that the axle is tightened by opening the lever completely and using it as a handle to screw the axle in. The slot in the axle head is not made of material that is strong enough to handle the torque required to fasten a bicycle wheel, so it starts to deform immediately.
After that, the lever is tightened and the cam built into the lever pushes the silver coloured cone into the axle, spreading the axle ends outwards. The outward pressure prevents the axle from becoming loose. The cam seems like it would operate like a QR axle cam, because it looks just like one, but this is a lie and it does not add any clamping load to the axle.
The small hole in the axle slot tries to act as a stress relief point, but it does not work if the axle is too loose. Or maybe it doesn't work at all. Maybe someone has closed the cam while the axle was not in the bike, making it expand so far that a crack started from the hole and eventually gave in completely.
Sadly, this is only the second stupidest through axle design I have seen on a Kona bicycle. It should be replaced with an axle that is tightened with an allen wrench.


My DT Swiss thru axles tell you to use at least 15Nm of torque. With such a short lever it really requires quite some force.

I completely rewrote my answer because I was completely wrong... An unbelievably horrible axle design.

@Torben, Now I remember, that I probably closed while, the cam (axle) was not inside the bike till the end. This axle is on Silverback Sprada 2.

Yeah, the Maxle Lite is known for being really soft. Most of them you see in the field have the edges mushroomed over like that. Granted, it is quite lightweight, living up to the name.

Strong, Lightweight, Expensive.  Choose two.

@mattnz isn't it "strong light cheap, pick any two?"
